# How to exclude an ingredient when ordering food?

Tags: word-choice, food, negation

I know I can order food using phrases like 我(想)要／请给我一份...

But how would I exclude an ingredient, e.g. if I don't like garlic?

我要一份青椒肚片无大蒜。

我要一份青椒肚片不要大蒜。

我要一份青椒肚片没有大蒜。

Would any of those be correct?

Answer (score 6):

Any of these sentences would be grammatically correct. However

`我要一份青椒肚片不要(加)大蒜`

would be a better and more common usage in my opinion.

It would be even better to include the character in the parenthesis,

`加`

which means "add" or "with" or "include".

Answer (score 4):

if you are speaking Cantonese, you can use

我要一份青椒肚片‘**走**’蒜。

in English it's something like take it off.

Comment: This usage of 走 comes from English. It's short for "without"; "thout" sounds like 走 in Cantonese.

Comment: @Stan, this usage of 走 has nothing to do with English.  It is a one-character version of "攞走", which means to remove or take out sth.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111287/discussion-on-answer-by-ah-hau-how-to-exclude-an-ingredient-when-ordering-food).

Answer (score 1):

我要一份青椒肚片不 **放** 蒜。

我要一份青椒肚片 **别搁** 蒜。 (more intensive than 不搁)

I think 放，搁 sounds more natural and navtivelike.

Comment: Wouldn't 不放 mean *not* without?

Comment: @RomanReiner 不放 here has the same usage as 不加

Comment: 不放 mean no put :)